# Can i get value of local variable dynamically from array of local variable name

Tags: java

Can i get the value of local variable from array of it's name by iterating the array.Below the code sample for the same.

```
public class TestLocalVar {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arrLocalVar = {"varA", "varB", "varC", "varD"};        
    String varA = "I am A";
    String varB = "I am B";
    String varC = "";
    String varD = "";           
    for(String localVarName : arrLocalVar){
        System.out.println("localVarvalue -->"+localVarName);
        //Here Can i get the value of local variable? 
    }       
    System.out.println("## Loop End ##");
    //Printing the values out side of the loop
    System.out.println("varA :"+varA+" ,varB :"+varB+ ", varC :"+varC+ " ,varD :"+varD);        
}}
```

This i am doing for validating local variables dynamically by iterating it's String type name Array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can but what is the excat problem you are facing

Comment: Insted of localVarName name i just want to get the value of array fields inside loop.So that i can validate the field value for empty and display all the empty local variable names.

Comment: Look at my response, localVarName would print out your values, but you initialized your array wrong.

Comment: @NDY, Yes..you are right.But my plan is the keep the string names  insted of values in an array.

Comment: Guess I missunderstood your intention. But as Abbé Résina mentioned, you cant get local variable values through reflection.

Comment: As stated, you are looking for a way to get the value of a local variable through its string name (given the string `"varA"`, find the value of variable named `varA`). Is it correct?  if so, this is called _reflection_ in java and read my answer...

Comment: @Abbe, Yes,you are right.i want to get the value of local variable by it's String name from array.

Comment: Then it's only possible for class members, not local variables. You can may be review your problem in order to have these local variables _be_ field members of a class.

Comment: Thanks..@Abee, @NDY for your valid inputs.

Comment: What about using a `HashMap<String, Object>` where the key would be the name of the field you want to validate, and the value the value which can be of any type you need?

Comment: varA,varB,... values are coming from out side interface along with few other fields.I need to check the mandatory fields for empty values and return the empty field names in response.i can validate this using multiple if conditions but it looks ugly to me.thats why iam looking for some dynamic mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are not accessible through reflection. You have access to classes, class members (properties or methods), but not local variables used in methods or functions (static methods).

If you want to validate *fields* that are member of a class, then you can access them. The following code demonstrate how you can get the values of class instance fields through their *names*.

```
public class Foo {
   int a;
   String b;

   public Foo(int a, String b) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Foo foo = new Foo(42, "Hello there");

       try {
           Class<?> c = foo.getClass();
           // get an object that represent field "a" in class Foo
           Field a = c.getDeclaredField("a");
           Field b = c.getDeclaredField("b");

           System.out.println(String.format(
                   "foo a=%d, b=%s", 
                   a.getInt(foo), // get the value of field "a" for instance foo
                   b.get(foo)));
       } 
       catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Prints:

> foo a=42, b=Hello there

Answer (score 0):

The variable `localVarname` is only in the scope available of your current loop. You cant use it outside. If you want to use it outside, you need to declare a variable outside of the for loop. But this would not work for your case, because if you set your outside variable to the current `String` value, you override it with every loop.

```
for(String localVarName : arrLocalVar){
    // here you can use localVarname
}

// here you cant use localVarName, the variable doesnt exist anymore
```

But you can access the values of the array like that:

```
System.out.println("varA:" + arrLocalVar[0]); // prints varA
```

Btw, you defined your array like that:

```
String[] arrLocalVar = {"varA", "varB", "varC", "varD"};
```

Your array now has the values varA, varB, etc, but not actually your variable values. If you want to initialize it with the values from your variables, do it like that:

```
String[] arrLocalVar = {varA, varB, varC, varD};
```

This is probably the reason why you didn't get your expected result.